# raspberry pi i2c clock

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi, i2c

I am trying to create a clock with my raspberry pi. I am using [this](http://www.derekscholten.com/2013/09/02/raspberry-pi-sparkfun-7-segment-display-clock/) guide, and using the [supplied files](http://www.derekscholten.com/raspberrypi/pi7seg.tar.gz) (or trying to) I get the error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`
I cd into the directory, and run: `python clock_i2c.py`
It doesnt tell me what file it can't find, and unlike other questions, there isn't anything in the code trying to open anything. Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: check out `strace(1)`. The prior to last syscall it prints should be the problematic one.

Comment: I ran 'strace python clock_i2c.py'. I have no idea what any of this means. From skimming it it looks like it receives errors when it is trying to open stuff from python 2.7

Comment: These are the syscalls that your script executed. One of those failed and set `errno` to `ENOENT`. Find it and you will know what file exactly doesn't exist.

Comment: I have no clue what /dev/i2c-o is open:                                             ("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6fb6000
write(1, "[Errno 2] No such file or direct"..., 36[Errno 2] No such file or directory
) = 36
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, {0x2cf88, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, 8) = 0
exit_group(0)

Comment: Neither, do I but now you know which file it can't find, which could help you in pinpointing the problem.